# Laravel - mimes:pdf not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form with an input which allows to upload PDFs.

Here is the method that validates my input :

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'title' => 'required|max:255|string',
        'artist' => 'required',
        'notes' => 'nullable|string',
        'file' => 'required|mimes:pdf|max:500',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
    ]);
}
```

The rules are working for all the other fields, but it does not work for the file input. Whatever I upload, PDF or not, I have the following error :

> The file must be a file of type: pdf.

Answer (score 3):

I just solved my issue.

In case someone has the same problem, you need to set the `enctype` attribute of your form to `multipart/form-data`.

In short, something like this :

```
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...
</form>
```

The error is not very clear, so I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, that's a client side limitation. When you submit a form that contains a file to upload it won't be uploaded to the server. Laravel never sees the file so it's impossible to detect any problems from the server side unfortunately.